# mongodb update push array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I have the following schema.  I am using node.js with mongodb

```
attributes: {
    type: { type: 'string' },
    title: { type:'string' },
    description: { type:'string' },
    is_active: { type:'boolean',defaultsTo:true },
    createdBy: { type:'json' },
    attachments:{ type:'array' }
}

arr = [{
    'id':attResult.id,
    'subtype':type,
    'title'  : attResult.title,
    'body'  : attResult.body,
    'filetype' : attResult.filetype
}];
```

I am trying to push a attachments into the 'attachments' array that will be unique to the document.

This is the my query.

```
books.update(
    { id: refid },
    { $push: { attachments: arr } }
).done(function (err, updElem) {
    console.log("updElem" + JSON.stringify(updElem));     
});
```

What is the problem in my query,no error but not updated attachments.

I want my result to be this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : 5,
    "attachments": [
        { 
            "id": "xxxxxxx",
            "subtype": "book",
            "title": "xxxx",
            "body": "xxxx" ,
            "filetype" : "xxxxx"
        },
        {
            "id": "xxxxxxx",
            "subtype": "book",
            "title": "xxxx",
            "body": "xxxx",
            "filetype": "xxxxx"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What are you really using here? Mongoose perhaps? Do you mean "attributes" to be your schema definition? Or is the definition actually additional fields under a field called "attributes"?

Comment: You're trying to push an array, try pushing one item instead _or_ using a combination of `$each` with `$push`. [check here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/each/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your question a little bit more I'm betting that you are actually using "sails" here even though your question is not tagged as such.

The issue here is that the waterline ODM/ORM has it's own ideas about what sort of operations are actually supported since it tries to be agnostic between working with SQL/NoSQL backends and sort of demands a certain may of doing things.

The result is that updates with [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) are not really supported at present and you need more of a JavaScript manipulation affair. So in fact you need to manipulate this via a `.findOne` and `.save()` operation:

```
books.findOne(refid).exec(function(err,book) {
   book.attachments.push( arr[0] );
   book.save(function(err){
     // something here
   });
});
```

Part of that is "waterline" shorthand for what would otherwise be considered an interchangeable use of `_id` and `id` as terms, where just specifying the `id` value as a single argument implies that you are referring to the `id` value in your query selection.

So unless you replace the waterline ODM/ORM you are pretty much stuck with this AFAIK until there is a decision to maintain this logic in a way that is more consistent with the MongoDB API or otherwise allow access to the "raw" driver interface to perform these `.update()` operations.

For reference though, and has been alluded to, your general "shell" syntax or what would otherwise be supported in MongoDB specific drivers is like this with the deprecation of the [**`$pushAll`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pushAll/) operator and the intention being to merge the functionality with the [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) and [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) operators using the [**`$each`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) modifier:

```
db.collection.update(
   { "_id": ObjectId(refid) },    // should be important to "cast"
   {
      "$push": {
          "attachments": {
              "$each": arr
          }
      }
   }
)
```

So that syntax would work where it applies, but for you I am thinking that in "sails" it will not.

That gives you some food for thought, and some insight into the correct way to do things.

Comment: Hai thanks to all.i tried "_id" method.thats one also same problem.but  i tried mongodb save method  working .Thanks to all.

Comment: @user3046205 So you are using sails? I pretty much explained why that is the only way this works with sails is by retrieving the data then manipulating and then using `.save()`. It does help if you confirm this so we can re-classify your question as well as accepting the answer let's people know there was a solution.

Answer (score 10):

Someone who trying to push the element into an array  is possible now, using the native mongodb library.

Considering the following mongodb collection object

```
{ 
"_id" : 5,
"attachments": [
    { 
        "id": "xxxxxxx",
        "subtype": "book",
        "title": "xxxx",
        "body": "xxxx" ,
        "filetype" : "xxxxx"
    },
    {
        "id": "xxxxxxx",
        "subtype": "book",
        "title": "xxxx",
        "body": "xxxx",
        "filetype": "xxxxx"
    }
]
}


 arr = [{
 'id':'123456',
 'subtype':'book',
 'title'  : 'c programing',
 'body'  :' complete tutorial for c',
 'filetype' : '.pdf'
 },
{
 'id':'123457',
 'subtype':'book',
 'title'  : 'Java programing',
 'body'  :' complete tutorial for Java',
 'filetype' : '.pdf'
 }
];
```

The following query can be used to push the array element to "attachments" at the end. $push  or $addToSet can be used for this.

This will be inserting one object or element into attachments

```
db.collection('books').updateOne(
  { "_id": refid }, // query matching , refId should be "ObjectId" type
  { $push: { "attachments": arr[0] } } //single object will be pushed to attachemnts
 ).done(function (err, updElem) {
  console.log("updElem" + JSON.stringify(updElem));     
});
```

This will be inserting each object in the array  into attachments

```
   db.collection('books').updateOne(
     { "_id": refid }, // query matching , refId should be "ObjectId" type
     { $push: { "attachments":{$each: arr} } } // arr will be array of objects
     ).done(function (err, updElem) {
           console.log("updElem" + JSON.stringify(updElem));     
    });
```

Comment: add a bit of explanation to support your answer Ashokan

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert an `array` as an element into your array. You may want to look at `$pushAll` as a short term solution. This operator is deprecated however [see here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pushAll/).

Alternatively you can simply iterate over your array, and each iteration push an element from your array into `attachments` (this is the recommended approach by Mongo devs).

Comment: Hi martin, i tried  $pullAll still same problem. please help me how can i fix this issue.Tnks