# redis cache layer for mongodb queries for performance boost up

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis

i have an ecommerce site. my product catalog is in mongodb and all other transaction in mysql.
I am planing to use express middleware which will use redis as cache layer of all outgoing mongodb queries.

Can anybody help me out how to design the architecture?
I will be very thankful.
current technology stack nodejs+mongodb+mysql

Answer (score 0):

Generally redis will be very good for caching the data. Instead of hitting the main database for every request its good to go with caching technique, again it depends on how frequently you are updating the cache data. Serious issue will come if you miss to update the cache frequently or whenever the changes happen in the main databases. You have to listen to databases changes and update the cache, as of now there is no listener in may mongodb, so you can write some cron job to update the cache based on sometime. We need more details about the schema and architecture to help further.

#### Suggestion:

Step 1: Whenever you insert or update the data in `mongodb` or any main database, Add to cache `redis` database.

Step 2: So 99% data will available in cache `redis` database for particular product.

Step 3: Whenever making `api` a call based on the product or anyother detail, it will check it in `cache` redis database,  if that particular data exists return that data, Else fetch it from main database at the same time `add to cache` as well so next time you will get data from cache.

Hopefully this edit gives some more idea.

Comment: Thanks karthick. Generally i am planning this architecture for fetching product catalog part only. like fetching categories, subcategories, product details. so i want to cache the product details until it is not changed. I am planning to create a express middle ware which will communicate with redis and mongodb. So whenever i call api /products/:productId it will check if that product is cached or not so if product cached api will respond with cache data.

Comment: Check edit, Please add comments , Ready to help further

Comment: Ok thanks. will try to do this. Also can you tell me in mongodb how to push json data to existing field in a collection. Like i have **customer-order** collection which structure like this [http://plnkr.co/edit/MthQbDghMVs2wlhYb3gT?p=catalogue]

Comment: You have to change the schema like this {
 customerId: 1000,
 name:'jekjekjw',
 email: 'kjdkwd',
 phone: 88880808,

 orders: [{
  ordercode: 'ANCHJH123',
  amount: 13,000,
  products: [productId1, productId2, productId3]
 },
 {
  ordercode: 'JUYHJH123',
  amount: 1,000,
  products: [productId4, productId5, productId8]
 }]

}

Comment: Use array for orders , it will be easy to push that data. Check the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094129/mongodb-update-push-array)